# Dotnet garbage collector

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, garbage-collection

I have a dotnet application that i see it growing all time in terms of memory, than I decide to do some tests, starting by this code

```
Form f0 =null;
using(Form f1 = new Form())
{
   f0=f1;
   f0.Text="Hellow!";
   f0.ShowDialog();
}

f0.Text="Hellow, you here me";// exception attempt here but nothing happens.
```

that was my first question.

the second:
 when i have Control like `DataGridView` inside Form (and created in this form) marked by default as private;  suppose  i changed it to be public, i wante initialize Columns from external(from Form) Helpers, does it change the way of garbage collector?

Comment: Your code will not compile

Comment: sorry for 'Form'

Comment: A good habit is to check `IsHandleCreated` or `IsDisposed` (the former is used all the time in the .Net source code). A Control doesn't need to be `public` to be accessible from outside the class that owns it: you can pass its reference to another class anyway, in different manners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disposing an object does not mean it will be suddenly inaccessible in terms of garbage collection. Until you keep a reference to such an object it will be tracked by the GC.

So even though your form is disposed at the end of the `using` block, you can still access it via the `f0` reference you assigned. It seems, you can set some public properties of a disposed `Form` but try `f0.ShowDialog` outside of the `using` block and you will get an `ObjectDisposedException`.

<sub>As for the 2nd question: Without any code it is hard to say anything. But try not to mix multiple questions in one post. A generic answer to your generic question: do not keep any references from the helper class to the created instances and you will be alright.</sub>

Comment: actually, as long as f0 exists, or as long as you don't set f0=null, it will prevent garbage collection. Disposing is actually a process invented to release ressources not maintained by GC (unmanaged ressources). Although it's used for other cleanup processes today too. But it's cleanup - not destruction.

Answer (score 1):

**part1:** 
`f0=f1;` means that you have kept reference to the form object.

`Form.Dispose` (that is called in the end of `using` block) does not destroy the form object completely. It release certain unmanaged resources (like window and control handles, etc) however runtime objects (like `Form`) are still alive in the memory.
Those objects are marked as `ready to be garbage collected` but GC does not destroy them immediately.

That is why `f0.Text="Hellow, you here me"` operator works without null reference exception after `using`.

However `f0.Show()` after `using` will fail with `object disposed exception`

**part 2:**
GC calculates object references so helpers you are using should not break GC until they are keeping references on instances

```
class Helper
{
public void AddColumn(Grid grid, string name)
{
 grid.Columns.Add(new GridColumn(name));
}
}
```

this does not store reference on grid or gridcolumn instance so GC is not affected